# What is the most effective and recommended way to install Apache-PHP-MySQL in Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, apache2, xampp

Hi so far the servers I did for my studies were with Node.js.
I am starting a new job and I need to have installed an Apache-PHP-MySQL installation, it can be: XAMPP, MAMP or WAMP.
What would be the most effective option for my Ubuntu 18.04?
I've seen some tutorial in google but it was complicated and a bit messed up, maybe I did not find the correct tutorial, but that's why I decided to go here.
With effective I mean, the best way or the most recommended way and the best performance.
The utility is to create some application with PHP and MySQL
Thank you.

Comment: I will advice you to use docker containers for your lamp setup, with docker-compose. Easy enough to install and configure, replicable, and you won't pollute your OS.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package called `lamp-server` that installs them all and has all of the packages pre-configured to work out of the box where you see a "it works" when you open http://localhost.

[LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)) is what we use.

WAMP is WINDOWS so not useable. MAMP is MacOS so also not useable. Stay away from XAMPP. It is not suited for production systems so if you use that you will learn all the wrong things.

All you need on Ubuntu is ...

```
sudo apt install lamp-server^
```

and sit back until it finishes (well along the way you will need to add a password for MySQL but that should be it).

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1 - Install the Apache Server**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apache2
```

> If it is installed successfully then type **localhost** in the browser. You will see  something like this:

[image]

**Step 2 - Install MySQL Database**

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

**Step 3 - Install PHP**

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql
```

*Happy Coding! Happy Ubuntu!*

**Note:** if you got any error or an issue please edit your question